# CornerRadius not being applied

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my XAML I have the following bit of code to set a corner radius on my frame.

```
<Frame
    Padding="0"
    BackgroundColor="{Binding InitialCircleColor}"
    HasShadow="False"
    HeightRequest="40"
    HorizontalOptions="Start"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    WidthRequest="40">
    <Frame.CornerRadius>
        <OnPlatform
            x:TypeArguments="x:Single"
            Android="80"
            iOS="20" />
    </Frame.CornerRadius>
    <Label
        Padding="0"
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        FontSize="23"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
        Text="{Binding UserInitials}"
        TextColor="{Binding LetterColoring}"
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
</Frame>
```

I would expect it to be round as it used to be before we upgraded to the latest version of Xamarin, however, when I tried the above code in a separate new project it worked fine. What I am currently seeing is my frame being square.

Comment: Did you try delete bin/obj folders and rebuild ?

Comment: Have not tried that, though it is also actual in prod so i am not sure if that is the root cause

Comment: share screenshot

Comment: It might be a xamarin bug when using CreateSupportFragment

Comment: What about ```CornerRadius="{x:OnPlatform iOS='20', Android='80'}```?

Comment: Hmm, with single quotes? I will try that

Comment: @SomeStudent You mean that the CornerRadius don't work in your code? But I test your code in Android, it works fine.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I think it has to do with an open ticket in xamarin where using .CreateSupportFragment. I did try it in a different pure Xamarin.Forms project and that worked there

Comment: @SomeStudent Can you provide one simple sample at gtihub that can reproducing your problem?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT sure thing, once i am done with work today I will post it. Interestingly, I tried going around this by using a custom frame that just has its own corner radius and it only works on one page where it actually properly reads the data whilst the other pages it is on always have a the value of 0 for its corner radius regardless of what it is set to

Comment: @SomeStudent You better share your entire sample, because we are difficult to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Effect to set **CornerRadius** if the above still doesn't work on your side

#### in Forms

```
public class FrameCornerRadius : RoutingEffect
  {
    public FrameCornerRadius() 
      : base("YourProject.FrameCornerRadiusEffect")
    {
    }

    public float CornerRadius { get; set; }
  }
```

#### in iOS

```
using Foundation;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using xxx;
using xxx.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName(nameof(xxx))]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(FrameCornerRadiusEffect), nameof(FrameCornerRadiusEffect))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
  [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
  public class FrameCornerRadiusEffect : PlatformEffect
  {
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
      try
      {
        var effect = (FrameCornerRadius)Element.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is FrameCornerRadius);
        if (effect != null)
        {
          Container.Layer.CornerRadius = effect.CornerRadius;
          Container.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
        }
      }
      catch (System.Exception ex)
      {
        throw new System.Exception($"Cannot set property on attached control. Error: {ex.Message}");
      }
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
      
    }
  }
}
```

#### in Android

```
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Views;
using System.Linq;
using xxx;
using xxx.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName(nameof(xxx))]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(FrameCornerRadiusEffect), nameof(FrameCornerRadiusEffect))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
  class FrameCornerRadiusEffect : PlatformEffect
  {
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
      try
      {
        var effect = (FrameCornerRadius)Element.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is FrameCornerRadius);
        if (effect != null)
        {
          Control.ClipToOutline = true;
          Control.OutlineProvider = new RoundedOutlineProvider(effect.CornerRadius);
        }
      }
      catch (System.Exception ex)
      {
        throw new System.Exception($"Cannot set property on attached control. Error: {ex.Message}");
      }
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
    }
    
    private  class RoundedOutlineProvider : ViewOutlineProvider
    {
      private readonly float radius;
      public RoundedOutlineProvider(float radius)
      {
        this.radius = radius;
      }
      public override void GetOutline(Android.Views.View view, Outline outline)
      {
        outline?.SetRoundRect(0, 0, view.Width, view.Height, radius);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you can use it like

```
<Frame.Effects>
     <local:FrameCornerRadius CornerRadius="{OnPlatform Android='50', iOS='15'}" />
</Frame.Effects>
```

Comment: Might have to do that, I will try it after the holidays. thank you kindly

Comment: Sadly on my android (haven't checked iOS yet) the Control appears to always be null.